# How to handle PostMessage() failing?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I want to send a message to the UI thread using `PostMessage()`, and I need to guarantee that the message is actually sent. However, `PostMessage()` can fail, so how should I handle the case when it fails, should I place it in a while loop that does not exit until `PostMessage()` returns success?

Comment: Call TerminateProcess() so your code cannot do more damage.

Answer (score 2):

Since you *can't* guarantee delivery, as you indicate yourself, you need to instead decide how bad failure is. It sounds pretty critical, so I'd simply terminate the app. What else could you do?